# Error en mi código de python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer un código para graficar los armónicos de la serie de fourier pero me marca un error en una línea de impresión:

***print("\ n"+"an = ")*** me marca **Invalid syntax(py flakes E)** , el código completo es este:

```css
from sympy.abc import t, n

ao = integrate(1, (t, 0, 1 / 2))


print("\n"+"a0 =") 
pprint(ao)



an = integrate(cos(pi*n*t), (t, 0, 1 / 2))

               
print("\n"+"an =") 
pprint(an)

bn = together(integrate(bn*cos(pi*n*t), (t, 0, 1 / 2))

print("\n"+"bn = ") 
pprint(bn)

print("\n"+"f(x) = ")

armonicos = 120
serie = (ao/2)
for i in range(1, armonicos + 1):
    serie = serie + (an*cos(pi*n*t)).subs(n, i)
for j in range(1, armonicos + 1):
    serie = serie + (bn*cos(pi*n*t)).subs(n, j)
pprint(serie)
    
plotting.plot(serie, ylim=(-1, 1), xlim=(-1,5))
```

Comment: Qué error te marca?

Comment: Invalid syntax, pero solo me lo marca en una línea

Comment: Añade en que linea y cuál es el erro exacto. Edita la pregunta

Comment: lo agregué en la descripción

Comment: si no me equivo el \n es para salto de linea, ¿ que es lo qe intentas hacer?

Comment: es que igual sin el salto me marca el mismo error, a veces cuando agrego el salto ya no marca ese error y corre bien

Comment: ¿Desde dónde importas la librería `pprint`? En el módulo `sympy` no lo estás haciendo...

Comment: te falta un `from pprint import pprint`

Comment: Te falta un cierre paréntesis en la línea anterior `bn = together(integrate(bn * cos(pi * n * t), (t, 0, 1 / 2)))`